# Return Value from forEach array instance

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to return value from forEach array instance?

```
const numArr = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];

numArr.forEach(function (num, index, array) {
  console.log(array[index] + 100);
});
```

I was trying to return console.log value but it was returning last value sum.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. If you want to return a new array, don't use `forEach`, use `map`.

Comment: @MarkReed  i was experimenting with forEach, i am curious i can able to console.log bt i cannot whole array with new value.

please explain why it was like that

Comment: Because that's not what `forEach` does. It runs some code for each item in the array, but throws away the results; it's purely for side effects. If you want to keep the result, use `map`.

Comment: [RTM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#return_value)

Comment: If you want to have the forEach process the numArray, you can let it mutate the array: `numArr.forEach(function (num, index, array) {
  array[index] += 100;
});`

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you want to increase every element in the array.
You can do it using a `map` method.

```js
const numArr = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];

const newArr = numArr.map(v => v + 100);
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: why it was not possible to return a new value from forEach function?

Comment: What do you want to return a value from forEach for?

Comment: @Sairam.Gudiputis `.forEach()` doesn't return anything (and you're also not changing the content of `numArr`).